# Thread Safe Windows Form App running on the command-line

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, thread-safety

I have a Windows Form Application that can be run in quiet mode from the command-line. I found a class on the CodeGuru.com website which will handle executing a command-line process on an asynchronous thread. Here is the link for the demo and source. 
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c8503/Invoking-Command-Lines-Programmatically.htm#page-2

I've tested the demo stand-alone. Granted, it's a little old but it still works. I'm trying to adapt it to my application however there seems to be one slight difference which is causing my application to crash with an Invalid Operation Exception - Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'editExitTime' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

The demo application is launching from the frmMain which has a private static Main function. Running this way everything is happy.  When I move the Main Function to a class called "Program" and launch the form, it becomes thread-unsafe. I was thinking I might be able to use rtb.invokerequired but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Controversial solution: add line `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` to the program initialization code, and your application will predictably fail on every invalid cross-thread operation. Then solve the problem using `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Control.Invoke` methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to use, just copy/paste following

```
control.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    // put here some code to access control from other thread
    control.Text = "blablabla";
}));
```

where `control` is either of the controls with created handle (because whole GUI should be made in one thread).

And you may want to read more about `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` themselves, `InvokeRequired`, `HandleCreated`, as well as `Anonymous delegate`'s and `Lambda`'s to fully understand wtf is that ^^.